# Android ImageView bind srcCompact to a boolean Variable

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I've just discovered how to **bind variables** to xml files, it's quite hard the first times but it really speed up the work.

How can I bind a variable to an imageView so that ***if the vabiable (boolean) goes from true to false the ImageView SrcCompact change as well?***

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_indigo_a400_48dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
```

Here's my *Imageview* code with the BlueTooth Logo in Blue color. 
I'd like to bind it to a "**BluetoothEnable**" Boolean and, in case "**BluetoothEnable**" goes "**FALSE**" i want the *imageView* to show a *SrcCompact* with the **Bluetooth Logo in red**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought to share some solution if someone encounter this case.

When I tried to use the ternary expression, it didn't work for me:

```xml
<ImageView
    ...

    app:srcCompat="@{isBluetoothEnabled? @drawable/ic_bluetooth_green : @drawable/ic_bluetooth_red}"

    ... />
```

So, I tried the binding adapter approach.
Here I created a binding adapter, that will receive a boolean value for `isBluetoothEnabled` then based on it choose the proper drawable image:

```java
public class BindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("app:bluetoothBasedSrc")
    public static void setSendState(ImageView v, boolean isBluetoothEnabled) {
        int drawableRes = isBluetoothEnabled ? R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_green : R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_red;
        v.setImageResource(drawableRes);
    }

}
```

And here how we can use that binding adapter in the `ImageView`:

```xml
<ImageView
    ...

    app:bluetoothBasedSrc=@{isBluetoothEnabled}
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_green"

    ... />
```

Hope that solution helps this case.